# R installing OpenCL via install.packages with options

Tags: r, opencl, install.packages

I´m trying to install the package `OpenCL` in R on windows. I already installed openCL and have all header files (i.e. CL\opencl.h). It's in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\OpenCL SDK\6.1\include`. However, when I try to install `OpenCL` via:

```
install.packages("OpenCL",
                 type = "source",
                 # I tried many variations on this without any luck
                 INSTALL_opts = "C:/Program Files (x86)/Intel/OpenCL SDK/6.1/include")
```

then I get the following error:

```
ocl.c:6:23: fatal error: CL/opencl.h: No such file or directory
 #include <CL/opencl.h> 
                       ^
```

To me this means that R does not know where my `CL/...` folder is. How can I tell install.packages where it is? Similarly, how would I install this package via the command prompt? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think on Windows you want set that it your `PATH` variable.

Comment: I think you probably also want to set your `PKG_CFLAGS` environmental variables as noted in the `INSTALL` file [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/OpenCL/INSTALL).